# Ubuntu Touch - Bluetooth speakers playing while different screens are viewed

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

The other day I was playing a game on my Ubuntu tablet and I wanted some music to play through my Bluetooth speakers. So I connected the speakers and started to play the song via the Internet. I then returned back to the game at which point the music stopped, as the screen being displayed was not the music, but not the screen. On leaving the game and returning back to the music screen, the music started to play again.

So I cannot have music playing through the Bluetooth speakers without having the music page up. This meant that I could only use the tablet for one purpose (playing music from the net).

Is there a setting I can activate to allow the music to continue to play in the background (via the Bluetooth speakers), whilst I go to different screens on the tablet? If not this would be a really good idea to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are playing the music by using the browser.

Normally, only that app is being executed which is currently shown at your screen. This is done to bring the best performance to the currently used app and to extend your battery life.

This means if you switch from the browser to the game, the browsers stops running and your game continues excecution. If you switch back, the browser continues excecution and the game is stopped, thus you can't get a gameover in game while doing other things like writing some emails.;)

Nevertheless, thus its not possible to listen to music in browser at youtube and playing a game atthe same time.:(

What you coukd do instead: Use the musicplayer to listen to music, because this app is an exception of the above concept. Or switch on the Convergenced Mode on your tablet, because in this mode all aps are running at the same time.:)

Comment: Thank you for your comments above. That is a shame the two things cannot be run at the same time. I think I will add this as a feather as it was the browser I was using. May be a youtube app/scope may help. It would be such a great featuer without having to turn on the Convergenced Mode.

Comment: Thought I would raise this as a new feature oreven bug. The worst that can happen is that it is closed down. Bug #1583124

Comment: That is a good idea. Since OTA10 the browser prevents the phone from switching to standby if a video is shown. May be this feature can be improoved by preventing that the execution is stopped, too. Please share your link for the bugpost or the feature request here.;)

Comment: Hopefully, they will be able to implement it. I downloaded most of the youtube apps last night to see if one could help resolve the issue. However, most seem to be webapps, therefore the same issue. The bug has been raised as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluetooth-touch/+bug/1583124

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to do this is by playing music via the media player and then viewing other screens. This does mean that I do not have the selection of web sites such as YouTube.

The idea that you could use one screen to play music and another to play a game is a good one.